# Can we tune the exhaust system of a gasoline car to be as quiet as an electric car?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy, acoustics

Electric cars are quiet, so quiet that legislation is proposed in many countries, to make them audible to pedestrians, for obvious safety reasons.

My  question: is it possible, without getting into engineering or cost details more than the physics demands, so sticking to the fluid dynamics and acoustics aspects as much as possible, to design an exhaust system to create a silent internal combustion engine car.

This would, I suppose, be a car exhaust system which would be the equivalent of a silencer on a gun, and may follow many of  the same principles in relation to expansion of gases.

Comment: At moderate speeds the noise from conventional cars is mostly from the tires on the road and the air flow over the car, which the electric cars generate equally.  Your supposition is correct that if you want to muffle the engine noise better, you should use a larger muffler.  A muffler is like an RC filter-the volume is a capacitor that can absorb inputs of gases with relatively little change in pressure and the flow restrictions are like a resistor.  Raising R and C reduces the rolloff frequency, evening out the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the muffler does, as you learn the first time you have a car with a muffler that gets damaged.

The essential difference between gas and electric cars is that the gasoline power is derived from a carefully timed sequence of small explosions, in the pistons; the electric car does not have this phenomenon and will always be quieter for the same amount of muffling.

Comment: Thanks Rob,  I was never sure about  power losses. My  neighbours young son has gone in the reverse direction, if you follow me, it's like a shuttle lift off every morning...

Comment: omg @count_to_10, he's my neighbor too